# What languages use a conceptual parallel to the Hebrew verb ירש?

Tags: english, semantics, verbs, hebrew, grammatical-object

The Hebrew verb ירש is loosely translated to mean "inherit," but does not quite mean the same thing as the English word *inherit* because the Hebrew verb refers to an heir *inheriting his benefactor*, while the English verb *inherit* refers to an heir *inheriting property*.

Meaning, with the Hebrew ירש, we might say: "A son ירש his father"; while in English we would say "A son inherits his father's *property*." In both cases, the subject of the sentence is the heir/inheritor, but in Hebrew the object of the sentence is the *person* from whom the heir inherits, while in English the object of the sentence is *property* that is being inherited.

My question is: in what other languages (besides Hebrew) is the object of the verb for "inheriting" the deceased person whose property is being inherited, as opposed to the actual property (like in English)?

Comment: German has both, with closely related words: *Er erbt das Haus von seinem Vater* "He inherits the house of his father* and *Er beerbt seinen Vater* "He inherits from his father". German speakers have the choice what sense they want to emphasise.

Comment: In English the verb + preposition construction _inherit from_ has this meaning.

Comment: Der Erbe beerbt seinen Vererber. Der Vererber vererbt an die Erben. Der Erbe erbt das Erbe. (Das Vermögen ist ererbt.)
see Derived terms under https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/erben#German

Answer (score 2):

The Arabic cognate w-r-th ورث has both constructions: with direct object of a person (“inherit from someone”), or with a direct object of a thing (“inherit something”), or indeed with two direct objects (“inherit something from someone”).